# View to Another View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view which is a table of data.  The user has the ability to filter, hide columns and hide rows.  I need the user to be able to export the visible data to Excel and eventually pdf and possibly other.

My thoughts are that I get an array of ids from the visible rows and then an array of visible columns.  I then pass that to a controller which then builds the resultant model and return that to another view that has been set up specifically for exporting with slightly different formats from the original view.

I thought of using ajax and sending the arrays to the controller via ajax to build the needed model.  But then not sure how to proceed from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I do not really have code worth posting at the moment because still trying to have a plan first on what I am to do in the first place.  :)

Comment: What's exactly you question? Your plan seems to be practical and doable and needs some coding to gather data from client and send them to server.

Comment: My question is what should be the proper way to do this?  Am I headed down the correct path?  I will most likely have specific questions as I move along but before I start asking specific questions I thought I should back up a bit to make sure I ask the proper specific questions...make sense?

Comment: It seems to me that you are in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [datatables](http://datatables.net/). It provides all the functionality you need, like filtering rows, hiding columns and export to many file types including excel and pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately the main table has already been built out.  Very complex with next tables, colspans, etc.  So to move to datatables in your link would probably not be the correct direction for me.  Would not allow enough flexibility...  I think. But thanks!